# how to set the vertical scale of pyplot linear figure

Tags: python, plotly

I have a code that displays geologic well log in python using plotly,
the scale is linear and I set the range of it based on the dataframe index
I need to keep the scale as linear but want to set the vertical scale or the y-axis scale for example to be 1:100 how to achieve that

```
layout = go.Layout(
    title='VSH',
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=1500,
    yaxis=dict(
        title='DEPT',
        showgrid=True,
        showticklabels=True,
        gridcolor='#bdbdbd',
        gridwidth=2
    ),
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Vsh',
        showgrid=True,
        showticklabels=True,
        gridcolor='#bdbdbd',
        gridwidth=2
    )
)

df = df.loc[(df.index >= int(top)) & (df.index <= int(base))]
trace1 = go.Scatter(x = df['Vsh']/10 , y = df.index , mode='lines')
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1] , layout = layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list (for example, from 1 to 100):

```
list1 = [i for i in range(0, 101)]
```

and added two parameters to `yaxis` in `layout`:

```
yaxis=dict(tickvals=[i for i in range(len(list1))],
           ticktext=list1)
```

You can read more about `ticktext` and `tickvals` in plotly docs: [1](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-ticktext) and [2](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-tickvals).